# Jumping to certain tab by typing title text with autocomplete menu in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Is there a way or some add-on so that I can jump to certain tab by typing the title text with auto-complete menu in `Chrome`?

It get's a bit messy when there are too many tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few extensions with similar funcionality for Chrome.

[Tab Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-manager/coonecdghnepgiblpccbbihiahajndda) is open source and [TooManyTabs for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toomanytabs-for-chrome/amigcgbheognjmfkaieeeadojiibgbdp) seems to be pretty good (you have to enable "Show tabs across windows:" in options to make it work for all tabs, not just the tabs in the current window).